# Linear Algebra Help! Matrices with respect to given basis

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

Hey Guys I'm new here so I dont know much exactly how to do all the fancy symbols but here it goes:

Let $V_n$ be the vector space of real polynomials of degree at most $n$ and Let $B_n$ be the usual basis  $v_i$(t) = $t^{i-1}$ Define $T: V_2\to V_3$ by
$$
T(v(t)) = \int_{0}^{t} v(x)\,dx
$$
Let $D: V_3 \to V_2$ be the differentiation operator. Find the Matrices $[T]$ and $[D]$ with respect to the bases. Find $TD$ and $DT$ and their matrices

Verify that $[DT] = [D][T]$ and $[TD] = [T][D]$

now I found $[T]$ to be 
\begin{pmatrix}
0 &  0 &  0\\
1  &0   &0\\
0 & .5   &0\\
0&   0   &\frac 13\\
\end{pmatrix}
I cant figure out the rest though... is $[D]$ supposed to be a $3\times3$? or did I to $[T]$ totally wrong?

What exactly to they mean by $TD$?

Thanks guys

Comment: Please explain the integral operator further. Where does $v$ enter the right side? Or is that $Tv(x)=\int_0^x v(t) \,dt$, the anti-derivative operator?

Comment: yeah that exactly right. It is the anti-derivative operator

Comment: Your matrix for [T] is right, and the matrix for [D] should be 3x4 since $\dim(V_2)=3$ and $\dim(V_3)=4$.  By TD they mean the composition of T with D, so for example $TD(t^3)=T(3t^2)=t^3$.

Comment: @CesarCasarez I posted an answer, but there is a small problem with the definition of $V_n$ and $B_n$ in your question, so I may edit my answer. So is $V_n$ the vector space of real polynomials of degree at most n, OR, the vector space of real polynomials of degree smaller than n? Because if it is at "at most n", than $B_n$ is not a basis of that, as $t^n$ is missing.

Comment: @Zoltan Zimboras This is a good question; I didn't notice this discrepancy.

Comment: @user84413 Thx! Yes, we need to find that out. (And sorry, I answered also below a bit earlier.)

Answer (score 2):

You did it right for $T$. I guess this a homework problem, so let me give some help - but only hints. I will go through how to get $T$ (as you did it already) and then I will hint how to get $D$.

**Hints**

(1) Let us first clarify some points. Using your definitions, $T$ maps from a $3$-dimensional vector space to a $4$-dimensional one, hence $[T]$ should be $3 \times 4$ matrix. Consider the basis vectors $v(0)=1$, $v(1)=t$, $v(2)=t^2$, $v(3)=t^3$. Now $\{v(0), v(1), v(2) \}$ forms a basis for $V_2$, and $\{v(0), v(1), v(2), v(3) \}$ forms a basis for $V_3$.

Since we have that $T(v(0))=v(1)$, $T(v(1))=\tfrac{1}{2}v(2)$, $T(v(2))=\tfrac{1}{3}v(3)$ 
the matrix form of $T$, i.e. $[T]$, is as you wrote

\begin{pmatrix}
0 &  0 & 0\\
1  &0  & 0\\ 
0 & \tfrac{1}{2} & 0\\
0 & 0 & \tfrac{1}{3} 
\end{pmatrix}.

(2) On the other hand, since $D$ maps from a $4$-dimensional vector space to a $3$-dimensional one, hence $[D]$ will be a  $4 \times 3$ matrix. To get the entries of $[D]$ you have to calculate $D(v(0))$, $D(v(1))$, $D(v(2))$ and $D(v(3))$. For example, since $D(v(0))=0$ this means that the first column of $[D]$ consists only of zeros; while $D(v(1))=v(0)$ implies that the second column starts with $1$ and the rest of the entries in that column are zero. You can similarly find the other columns.

Can you find now the full matrix $[D]$?

(3) When you know the answer to (2), let us consider the maps $TD$ and $DT$. 
Since $T$ is a map from $V_2$ to $V_3$, and $D$ is a map from $V_3$ to $V_2$, 
$DT$ will be a $V_2 \to V_2$ map, and $TD$ will be a $V_3 \to V_3$ map. Hence $[DT]$ will be a $3 \times 3$ matrix, while $[TD]$ will be a $4 \times 4$ matrix. 
To find $[DT]$ you only need to calculate $DT(v(0))$, $DT(v(1))$ and $DT(v(2))$. For example, since $T(v(0))=v(1)$ and $D(v(1))=v(0)$, we have that $DT(v(0))=D(v(1))=v(0)$.
This means that the first column of the $3 \times 3$ matrix will start with $1$ and the rest of the entries in the first column are zero. You can also similarly find the other columns of $[DT]$ (and also of $[TD]$).

If you are done with finding $[DT]$, consider the matrix multiplication
$[D][T]$. Since $[D]$ is a $4 \times 3$ matrix and $[T]$ is a 
$3 \times 4$ matrix, $[D][T]$ will be a $3 \times 3$ matrix (as $[DT]$!). Perform the matrix multiplication and compare with the previously obtained $[DT]$ matrix. (And then do the same procedure once more: evaluate the matrix multiplication $[T][D]$ and compare that to matrix $[TD]$.)

Comment: I think T is mapping from a 3-dim space to a 4-dim one, since $\dim(V_n)=n+1$.

Comment: @user84413 There is a small problem with the definition of $V_n$ and $B_n$ in the question. I may edit my answer, if that will be clarified. So I don't know if $V_n$ the vector space of real polynomials of degree at most $n$, OR, the vector space of real polynomials of degree smaller than $n$? Because if it is at "at most $n$", than $B_n$ is not a basis of that, as $t^n$ is missing.

Comment: Vn is the vector space of real polynomials of degree less than or equal to n. Also, I forgot to state the the usual basis is defined by Vi(t) = t^(i-t)

Comment: OK, I accept it, but then $B_n$ should be $\{1,t,t^2,\ldots t^{n-1}, t^n \}$ - if it is to be the basis of $V_n$. I will edit my question assuming this. Please edit the question, writing this new $B_n$.

Comment: I fixed it on the question thanks again @ZoltanZimboras

Comment: @CesarCasarez Thanks! I fixed the answer accordingly. (And now I will go on editing the answer, to also give hints for the $DT$ and $TD$ part.)

Comment: @CesarCasarez and let me know whether from these hints the answer is clear, or whether I should expand on any of the points.